# Chat widget for Liferay

Tags: xmpp, chat, liferay, liferay-6

Can anybody recommend a chat client solution to integrate within Liferay, supporting chat rooms and to be used together with an XMPP server such as OpenFire? Obviously the more customisable, the better, also one that displays within the current page such as the native Liferay one, if possible.

Comment: Do you mean a portlet? or just a stand-alone XMPP client?
Liferay already integrates with Jabber on the server side, please see http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/1071674/Jabber+integration/maximized  So in principle, any chat client would work.  -- if you want a chatroom portlet, that's another matter.

Comment: Yes I need a chatroom. Portlet will do, that's fine.

Answer (score 2):

Please try Spark as your chat client,
You can customize it.

Comment: Had a quick look at Spark, it does look good indeed. Thanks. I struggle to find good documentation though. If you can point me to the configuration doc? What I have is different Liferay servers running and I want a federated chat capability between them. I need autologin as well so that the user does not have to login separately.

Comment: one of my friend did this, i will try to get the information and reach you soon,